# How to split a file based on a group of Header, Details etc in Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file that look like below.

```
File Date Source Target                     
HD|Field1|Field2|Field3  
ITEM1|Other fields1  
ITEM2|Other fields2  
HD|Field1|Field2|Field3  
ITEM1|Other fields  
ITEM2|Other fields  
ITEM3|Other fields
```

I need to create separate files based on the occurrence of HD. First file will contain lines starting from HD and will have everything till the next HD segment starts.

There can be N number of HD segments. The files also need to be renamed based on Field1 value of HD segment.

So file 1 will be as File-Field1 and would contain

```
HD|Field1|Field2|Field3  
ITEM1|Other fields1  
ITEM2|Other fields2
```

File 2 will be File-Field1(of 2nd HD segment) and would contain

```
HD|Field1|Field2|Field3  
ITEM1|Other fields  
ITEM2|Other fields  
ITEM3|Other fields
```

I need some help in getting the batch script. I have done some basic code and it looks like below.

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set limit=1 
set file=Sample.txt 
set lineCounter=1 
set filenameCounter=1 
set name= 
set extension= 
for %%a in (%file%) do ( set "name=%%~na" set "extension=%%~xa" ) 
for /f "skip=1 delims=," %%a in (%file%) do ( set 
splitFile=Load-!name!!filenameCounter!!extension! 
if "%%a"=="HD|" ( set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1 set 
lineCounter=1 echo Created !splitFile!. ) echo %%a>> !splitFile! set /a 
lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1 )
```

With this I get only 1 file and the line with HD| but the name is fine as Load-Sample1.txt. However there is huge loss of data. What I tried is to do a loop that will skip the first line and then in the for loop create a new file everytime a HD| is encountered.

Comment: What did you tried? What did not work?

Comment: Oh I can help, just put `@echo off` first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brittle pure batch solution (lots of ways the code can break depending on the content of the source file)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "outfile="
for /f "delims=" %%A in (sample.txt) do (
  for /f "delims=| tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%%A") do if "%%a"=="HD" set "outfile=%%b"
  if defined outfile echo(%%A>>"!outfile!"
)
```

Here are some of the ways the above code could fail:

- Empty lines will be stripped
- Lines beginning with `;` will be stripped
- Lines containing `!` will be corrupted

The code could be made more robust, but it will become significantly more complicated. I would not bother. Pure batch is a terrible language for text file manipulation, except for the simplest of tasks. It is slow, and requires loads of arcane knowledge.

I have [added a new feature (v6.8)](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044&start=315#p53520) to my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processor](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) that makes it trivial to create a fast and robust solution for this problem.

JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

I use a regular expression to locate HD lines and extract the file name. I use custom JScript to open a new output file at each HD line.

```
jrepl "^HD\|([^|]+)" "openOutput($1);$txt=$0" /jq /f "sample.txt" >nul
```

Be sure to use CALL JREPL if you use the command within another batch script. However, CALL will double the quoted caret, and a caret could technically be part of a file name. So you should also use another new feature of version 6.8 - the new `\c` caret escape sequence. This will hide the caret from CALL so it does not get doubled.

```
call jrepl "\cHD\|([\c|]+)" "openOutput($1);$txt=$0" /x /jq /f "sample.txt" >nul
```

Comment: I spit it in the chat rooms ear and got some feedback sir... https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access